# set default value for avro schema field in java

Tags: avro

how do we set default value of a field in avro schema by using java.
By using Schema object we can extract the schema and get Fields retrieves all the fields in a list.

List fields = schema.getFields();

by iterating over the fields we can set and get all the attributes of the field except default. DefaultValue() can only be retreived.
Do anyone know how to set default value for a field.is their any workaround for this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

found the solution by going through the avro api.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the default value while creating the field

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.5.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.Field.html